# Executing command remotely on another linux server from a shell script

Tags: linux, ssh, shell-scripting, awk, unix-shell

I have a shell-script which extract details from a log file between two dates and executes a command on the output to generate some report.The log files are on different server and scripts are executed on different server. the Script looks like :

```
#!/bin/sh
time1=$1
time2=$2
echo `ssh -i key  user@ip -yes cat file | awk '{if(substr($4,2)>="'$time1'" && substr($4,2)<="'$time2'") print $0;}'` > tmp.log

`cat tmp.log | some operation to get detail`
```

The output expected to be like :

```
ip1 date1 - - request1 file1 method1 status1 
ip2 date2 - - request2 file2 method2 status2
```

i.e. multiple lines but the output generated is a single line containing all the details like:

```
 ip1 date1 - - request1 file1 method1 status1 ip2 date2 - - request2 file2 method2 status2
```

When running the same command directly on the server its generate desired output but not when executed remotely.
So my question is how would I get the correct output and is this a good way to do this ?

Comment: echo eats your newlines, see here http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.shell/2007-05/msg00584.html

Comment: Thank you  it really worked. I just added the command inside **""** without removing backticks and it worked.

Comment: @anand As you have your answer, would you be willing to add it as an answer to your own question? Else this question will get a lot of attention from people looking to answer it, only to find out it already has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in various places (like this one http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.shell/2007-05/msg00584.html) echo outputs its arguments separated by spaces

Therefore you either have to pass the result of the command in the backticks as one argument

```
echo "`some command that outputs multiple lines here`"
```

Or not use `echo` but for instance `printf`